# Option data analysis

Tags: options, option-pricing, american-options

This question is regarding the following tweet: https://twitter.com/yuriymatso/status/1281730109141954561

How was the original tweeter able to know that "Someone made a `$`650K bullish bet via 24 July'20 $340 calls expecting SPY to go up at least 8% in the next 2 weeks." I am not saying what he said was right or wrong but just what did he see or where he saw what data which had him conclude this statement. I am sure this was something he may have seen in the option chain perhaps. Any help or even if you could possibly point to a resource would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He circled the volume of the option in question. It was roughly 50,000 and one option contract is usually for 100 shares. Price was 0.13.

$50k*100*0.13 = 650k$

Comment: Thank for your explanation! Quick question, do you know why it is an unusual volume?

Comment: You can see the volume of each option traded each day, so if this volume was larger than the normal volume you see trading in options...